# Lentitud del SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-data-studio, sql-server-management

Mi sql server management studio 2019 se puso muy lento de un momento a otro, cuando quiero desplegar las tablas en el explorador de objetos, abrir algún objeto, diagrama o procedimiento almacenado demora unos cuantos segundos incluso minutos, cosa que antes no hacía.
Precisamente esto comenzo a suceder despues de que conecte mi base con Google Data Studio. sin embargo elimine dicha conexion de Data Studio, pero la base sigue lenta.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

Comment: Pueden ser muchas razones. Pero hay libros enteros dedicados a esto y tal como está la pregunta, no creo que pueda ser respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor trata lo siguiente en el startup de SSMS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configura SSMS para evitar el spalsh screen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trata de abrir Internet Explorer, y ve al tab Options/Advance. Haz un scroll al final de la lista y descoteja "Check for publisher's certificate revocation". Cuando SSMS inicia él trata de conectarse al Certificate Revocation List (CRL) de Microsoft. Los componentes .NET components de SSMS tratan de contactar el Certificate Revocation List y SSMS no logra hacerlo. Esto hace que se ponga lento el proceso de carga inicial de SSMS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]